# How to get Images from Cursor in android?

Tags: android, image, cursor

i want to get the images from the cursor . i am using Mediastor.image.data 
here is my code

```
    String los=getArguments().getString(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER1);
        Uri mImageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;





  final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED};
        ContentResolver mContentResolver = rootView.getContext().getContentResolver();

        Cursor mCursor = mContentResolver.query(mImageUri, columns, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",new String[] {los}, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

//your UserContract class

```
public class UserContract {

public static abstract class NewUserInfo
{

         public static  final String IMAGE = "image";

}}
```

//In your dbhelper class

```
public DataProvider getInformations()
{
    ArrayList<DataProvider> ListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<DataProvider>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select " +UserContract.NewUserInfo.IMAGE+" from "+UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, null );
    res.moveToFirst();
    DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider();
    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){

        dataProvider.setImage(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(UserContract.NewUserInfo.IMAGE)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    return dataProvider;

}
```

//In your activity

```
Context context = this;     
UserDbHelper userDbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
Cursor cursor;    
String image;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
userDbHelper =new UserDbHelper(this);
    DataProvider dataProvider=userDbHelper.getInformations();

    image = dataProvider.getImage();

}
```