# Android Upload Image using path or uri?

Tags: android, uri, android-file

I'm having a trouble bringing the images from the gallery to my app.

The hard part is that, in some articles they use uri rather than path, but in others vice versa.

Plus, I'm not also sure... when I get Uri from the intent coming back, should I use cursor to get images data? ([How to get Images from Cursor in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915111/how-to-get-images-from-cursor-in-android)) In some other references, they do it in the easy way, just with 'getPath()' method.

Do I need either of path or uri? or Only one of these?

I'm so confused now..

Comment: Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/sample.jpg"))

Comment: @RamMohandubey In some examples, they convert uri to path, and in others path to uri. What is the right thing?

Comment: try this : https://www.journaldev.com/23219/android-capture-image-camera-gallery-using-fileprovider

Answer (score 0):

Always use Uri:

`File file = new  File(uri.getPath());`

then

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

and when you have bitmap simply load it in to ImageView

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: also check if  file exists

Comment: Thank you! If the uri is the one that's really needed, then, if i can get directly get uri, with 'data,getdata()' ( I used 'ACTION_PICK' intent ), don't i need to get path of this file?

Comment: can you post some code please so it would be more clear?